# How to blacklist a particular bad RAM area in Windows?

Tags: windows, memory, kernel, memtest86+, boot.ini

I have found a RAM error with MemTest86+ (the version included with Ubuntu 13.04), it says:

```
Failing address: 002f796c48 -    759.5 MB
```

I have no money to buy new RAM now and the error seems to be single so I hope I can just override it.

In Linux there is a `memmap` kernel parameter that can be specified in the boot loader configuration file lets to blacklist a particular RAM area easily.

Perhaps there is a similar parameter `boot.ini` parameter or other way to do the same in Windows? I am interested in both Windows 7 and XP solutions.

Comment: Related question: http://superuser.com/questions/420051/running-windows-with-defective-ram

Answer (score 1):

[`/BURNMEMORY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/troubleshoot/windows-server/performance/switch-options-for-boot-files#burnmemorynumber) and [`/MAXMEM`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/troubleshoot/windows-server/performance/switch-options-for-boot-files#maxmemnumber) Boot.ini options.

See also [Boot Parameters to Manipulate Memory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/boot-parameters-to-manipulate-memory).

Comment: -1 - this doesn't seem to answer the question at all. where is one to put the address of the failing byte of memory?

Comment: @tapped-out morning)))

Comment: Having read the linked article I still don't understand what of the options to use at all and what to specify to skip a single byte but not the bytes remaining after it (it doesn't look reasonable  to limit yourself with just 759 MB out of 4 GBs when just a single bit is bad).

Comment: @Ivan - You asked for a solution and this is it.  The only other solution is to simply remove the bad memory.  That will just be a trial and error operation.