# How to install Linux/Windows with bad RAM

Tags: linux, windows, memory, hardware-failure, memtest86+

I have a sub-notebook (Sony VAIO SVP) where Windows boots to a BSOD. By now, I have found out that the RAM has some errors. Since RAM, CPU and FlashDrive are solderd to the board and the warranty has expired I can only throw it away or try to work around the problem.

I have run Memtest86+ for about 12 hours and found some errors. I configured it according to [this guide](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/75059/how-to-blacklist-a-correct-bad-ram-sector-according-to-memtest86-error-indicati) to output the BadRAM parameters.

The faulty RAM is at ~700 MB, which enabled me to use a small live-linux to do a dd copy of the harddisk. (Which I can mount and read on another PC). So the data can be deleted.

Now I want to install Windows or Linux on this system. Installing Windows fails at some point; probably because it uses more than 700 MB and therefore hit the faulty section of the RAM. It seems to be possible to tell Windows about the faulty ram ( [How to blacklist a particular bad RAM area in Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/592870/how-to-blacklist-a-particular-bad-ram-area-in-windows) ), but I have no idea how to set these parameter in a way that the setup also works.

Therefore Linux seems more promising. Ubuntu seems to have the best support for BadRAM, therefore I would like to use Ubuntu. (Nut I am also fine with other distributions like Debian, *buntu, CentOS, Fedora or even Gentoo)

**The question is: how can I tell the setup to obey the badram settings?**

The next thing would be: how can I be sure that the remaining RAM does work correctly?

Should I run Memtest86+ for more hours? How many?

Can I test the RAM from within Ubuntu?

Comment: Why wouldn't you just replace the bad memory module?

Comment: As stated above they are soldered to the mainboard. This is a 900 gram sub-notebook. Everything is soldered in place.

Comment: The best you could do is try BadRAM, blacklist the sector that is faulty, and then run Memtest to see if you get any errors. From that point on, you would just have to use the system and hope more sectors don't go bad.