# Bad sectors in RAM, fixed or not?

Tags: windows, memory, sectors

So I have blocked some bad memory range from RAM memory. 
My Question is the next one, I have done it right?

Here you have the info:

```
C:\Windows\system32>bcdedit /set badmemorylist 0xFC 0xFD 0xFE 0xFF
The operation completed successfully.

C:\Windows\system32>bcdedit /enum

Windows Boot Manager
--------------------
identifier              {bootmgr}
device                  partition=\Device\HarddiskVolume1
description             Windows Boot Manager
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {globalsettings}
default                 {current}
resumeobject            {d9b18246-6fc0-11e8-aa41-d80cde060b56}
displayorder            {current}
toolsdisplayorder       {memdiag}
timeout                 30

Windows Boot Loader
-------------------
identifier              {current}
device                  partition=C:
path                    \Windows\system32\winload.exe
description             Windows 10
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {bootloadersettings}
displaymessageoverride  Recovery
recoveryenabled         No
testsigning             Yes
badmemorylist           0xfc
                        0xfd
                        0xfe
                        0xff
allowedinmemorysettings 0x15000075
osdevice                partition=C:
systemroot              \Windows
resumeobject            {d9b18246-6fc0-11e8-aa41-d80cde060b56}
nx                      OptIn
numproc                 8
bootmenupolicy          Standard
usefirmwarepcisettings  No

C:\Windows\system32>bcdedit /set badmemoryaccess no
The operation completed successfully.
```

And the memtest will be shown:

[image: Memtest]

Comment: +1 I did not know BCDedit    could map out bad RAM segments. I suppose there are limitations depending on word    boundaries

Comment: I don't think there's any problem with the question except for the incorrect term usage. I didn't know that Windows can also block fault memory ranges like grub [Running windows with faulty memory which can not be replaced](https://superuser.com/q/956480/241386)

Comment: +1 for this undocumented feature. You seem to have done it right,as far as the non-documentation goes. You will can know the answer just by using the computer.

Comment: No, I didn't. Anyway, the FIX for this is it on my profile.

Comment: @harrymc it seems that the feature was documented but it's less wellknown https://superuser.com/a/490522/241386 https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/boot-parameters-to-manipulate-memory

Comment: @phuclv: I referred to the Microsoft doc, which does not include `badmemorylist`. Weird.

Comment: @harrymc it's mentioned [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/whea/how-to-manage-the-pfa-memory-list) only which was linked in the answer I commented above