# Can this SSD be salvaged?

Tags: ssd, chkdsk, smart

I have an SSD drive that I have determined to be the source of many random BSODs and hangups, as detailed in [What is causing this ntoskrnl.exe BSOD?](https://superuser.com/questions/1308627/what-is-causing-this-ntoskrnl-exe-bsod). Apparently the drive fails in some way, but both S.M.A.R.T. And Chkdsk report the drive as being just fine. I've since installed a new drive, but it would be a shame to just throw the old ssd away if it can be salvaged. What avenues - if any - are available to diagnose and repair the problem when the aforementioned tools fail to find any?

Comment: Did you try a secure wipe yet?

Comment: I've formatted the drive, but that's it. How would a secure wipe resolve these hardware errors?

Comment: Check if it’s under warranty - if so then you might be able to get a repair/replacement if you can prove it’s faulty.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be in many areas:

- the drivers (chipset usually)
- the RAM
- the SSD cable (although this can also cause SMART events)

If you want to make sure the disk is fine, get HDTune and perform a full read test. If it's all green, it's fine and you'll have to investigate the other issues