# Block defective RAM sectors

Tags: windows, memory, blocking, sectors

How do I find defective RAM sectors and where?
I have tried memtest, but where it does describe the sectors (if).
And how to solve them exactly. First, i have tried this : https://thecomputerperson.wordpress.com/2015/04/20/how-to-block-out-or-map-out-bad-ram-in-windows/ but i don t think it's working cause I have written the wrong adresses.

Next thing, i will attach the memtest scrs.  [HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/79Clg.png)

If I got them right(bad adresses from memtest), can you help me convert RAM to pages so I can block them properly in BCD?

Thank you.

Comment: Memory does not have sectors, it has addresses, what your looking to do is confusing

Answer (score 1):

Stefan, I don't believe what you're trying to accomplish is possible on Windows (Linux, yes).

See this answer:
https://superuser.com/a/421028/74099

> ... you cannot instruct windows in any way to not use certain memory
>   addresses. The only way would be for Microsoft to patch the kernel for
>   your case specifically. Unlikely.

Comment: I think it worked with that.